# How do add body in email VBA macro when paste to picture is already in use?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

So I have a macro on Excel VBA which drafts an email with receiver, subject, and paste of a table using a selected range. When I use the body function it doesn't add to the body. How would I do this? Here's what I did so far.

```
Sub Mail_Button()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim Email As Object
    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wd As Date
    wd = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1)
    
    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report & Email")
    Set rng = Sht.Range("B1:F9")
        rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor

    With Email
        .To = "person@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Report - For " & Format(wd, "mmmm dd, yyyy") & " Session"
        .Body = "Please see attached the report for yesterday."
        
        wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
        
    End With
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set Email = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox ("Done!")
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The body is set alright. But the `Inspector.WordEditor.PasteAndFormat` seems to override the body once the mail is actually shown (for this see the `Debug.Print` messages) - From what my tests showed: only after Displaying is the new (and final) body actually set.

With that knowledge we can get the HTMLBody of the mail after the Paste has occurred. The HTMLBody is just a String representing the Mail Body in HTML format. Into that string we can insert our own HTML (which could for example be the additional text you desire). In my example I deleted the closing tags (to get into the `body`(tag) of the `html`(tag); added the elements I needed (in my case a `div` element with some text inside and then added the before deleted closing tags again. This way I inserted some content into the HTML Body.

Just using the `body` property for this will not work, since the table can not be converted into just a string (only a string representing the table in HTML format)

```
With Email
    .To = "person@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "Report - For " & Format(wd, "mmmm dd, yyyy") & " Session"
    .Body = "Test"
    Debug.Print "body before Paste: " & .Body
    wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
        
    Debug.Print "body after paste and before display: " & .Body
    .Display
    Debug.Print "body after display: " & .Body
        
    myHTMLBody = .HTMLBody
    myHTMLBody = Replace(myHTMLBody, "</body></html>", "")
    myHTMLBody = myHTMLBody & "<div> Test text that is shown below the table </div></body></html>"
    .HTMLBody = myHTMLBody
End With
```

You could just aswell delete the openeing Tags and markup of your HTML-Body in order to insert Elements before the Table.

Another way could be to construct the whole mail with the `Inspector.WordEditor` (so not just the pasting but the text adding as well. But if and how this would work I don't know, since I have never before used the Inspector.WordEditor to construct mails in VBA

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub SendEmailWithRange()
    Dim rng As Range, x
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim wd As Date
    wd = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1)
    
    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report & Email")
    Set rng = Sht.Range("B1:F9")
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    
    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display'Change to .Send to send the email immediately
        
        .Body = "Please see attached the report for yesterday."
        
        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        
        x = doc.Range.End - 1
        rng.Copy
        doc.Range(x).Paste
            
        .To = "person@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Report - For " & Format(wd, "mmmm dd, yyyy") & " Session"
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
    
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```